# windows mobile 6.5 .net CF - how to get notification that the internal phone turns on or off

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, event-handling

Which API can I use to get notifications about state change of teh phone? For instance I have my application and want to know wheter the user turns off or on the phone from Wireless Manager?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status;

var phoneRadioOffState = new SystemState(SystemProperty.PhoneRadioOff);

phoneRadioOffState.Changed += (sender, e) =>
{
    var off = Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue);

    // Here you can do whatever you'd like when the phone is on or off.
};
```

Just remember that the `phoneRadioOffState` must be in scope/alive for the event handler to be called, so it's usually not a good idea to make it a method-local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the State and Notification Broker to watch the PhoneRadioOff property.  An example of setting up the broker [can be found here](http://www.developer.com/ws/pc/article.php/3547381).